# Why was it reasonable to ask what the higher K-groups are?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, at.algebraic-topology

To say I am a novice in $K$-theory is to overstate my experience with the field. I've been reading the various wiki articles so as to have some preparation before jumping in, and I couldn't answer the following question to myself:

I understand that $K$-theory had started with the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch in mind, and that the only thing that was needed for that purpose from $K$-theory was just to define the Grothendieck Group ($K_0$). Once the idea of the Grothendieck group was established, this was generalized to topological spaces, as well as for other kinds of modules. Then comes the step I don't understand -- it seems that people were then trying to find the higher $K$-groups that would make $K$-theory into a cohomological theory. Milnor came up with Milnor $K$-theory, which I understand from wiki is different from later notions of higher $K$-theory. But why would one leap from the concept of the Grothendieck group to thinking that this construction is the $0^{th}$ step in a cohomological theory? What was the context/motivation for that?

Comment: I am not an expert on the history of $K$-theory, but I am pretty sure that the most important motivation for higher algebraic $K$-theory was the existence of higher topological $K$-theory. Higher topological $K$-theory was constructed by Atiyah and Hirzebruch (using the Bott periodicity theorem).


Comment: I think Milnor's book (Intro to Algebraic K-theory) gives a pretty good indication of why people expected a "higher" K-theory (even if some of the reasons presented in the book later turned out to be mistaken, e.g. the Mayer-Vietoris sequence doesn't extend past K_2 in general).  But the book makes it clear that the three functors K_0, K_1, and K_2 (which all have geometric meanings/applications) are linked in ways that resemble a cohomology theory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea of considering higher K-groups comes from topology, and is due to Atiyah, Bott, and Hirzebruch. Atiyah and Hirzebruch defined topological K theory  and observed that Bott periodicity says that $K(X)$ is more or less the same as $K(S^2X)$. This suggested to them defining a  generalized cohomology theory of period 2 by using all the groups $K(S^nX)$ (this was the first example of a generalized cohomology theory). Once one realizes that topological $K^0$ can be extended to topological $K^n$, it does not take much imagination to suggest that algebraic $K^0$ also has an extension to algebraic $K^n$. (Of course, finding this extension was much harder than guessing it existed.)

Answer (score 16):

After having defined *K*<sub>0</sub>, a natural things to do is to study its functoriality properties.
You do that, and you notice some exact sequences... that you happen to be able to extend a 
bit by using the functors *K*<sub>1</sub>, and then later *K*<sub>2</sub>.

It is then natural (specially if you know what cohomology is) to try to find long exact sequences that extend the above sequences... A lot of people tried to do that.

Quillen's brilliant idea was to *define* algebraic *K*-theory as the homotopy groups of an appropriately constructed space. In that way, the long exact sequences came as natural consequences of known long exact sequences in topology.

 Slogan: *Homotopy theory is the mother of all long exact sequences.*

*Aside:* I also recommend reading Thomason's work on algebraic *K*-theory of schemes: it's beautifully written!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it is unlikely that Quillen was the first to realize that the algebraic K-groups should be the homotopy of some space.  Swan and Karoubi (and quite possibly others) had the same idea.  The problem, of course, was to find the right space.

Comment: I chose the other answer because it was more directed at the question, but this was also a very helpful answer. Do you have a precise name for Thomasson's work, so I can look it up?

Comment: Thomason, R. W.; Trobaugh, Thomas:
Higher algebraic K-theory of schemes and of derived categories. The Grothendieck Festschrift, Vol. III, 247–435, 

Comment: In Milnor's book on the functor $K_2$, he motivates the story in the way André mentions: a pushout diagram of rings gives rise to a Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $K_0$ and $K_1$. Milnor was motivated by this observation when giving a definition of $K_2$. Regarding uniqueness, note that $K_0(R)$ is the universal receptacle for invariants of f.g. projective $R$-modules additive on exact sequences. Likewise, $K_1(R)$ can be viewed as the universal gadget for invariants of f.g. projective $R$-modules equipped with automorphisms. There's a related description for $K_2$, but I'm out of space.

Comment: @JohnKlein That's sad! Could you please expand on a universal characterization of $K_2$? It is very interesting!